# H2 Database - on primary key conflict replace

Tags: java, sql, h2

I would like to make the H2 Database engine replace the conflicting entriy if a entry is being inserted and it conflicts with another record having the same PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE value.

I can do the same in SQLite with the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE STACKOVERFLOW(FOO TEXT IDENTITY ON CONFLICT REPLACE);
```

This is called a [conflict clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) in SQLite.

Can I replicate this behaviour in the H2 SQL dialect?

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge

Comment: That is it! @a_horse_with_no_name If you write a quick answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the `MERGE INTO` statement, in my case I was able to just replace the `INSERT` statement with `MERGE INTO`:

```sql
MERGE INTO TABLE STACKOVERFLOW('abc');
MERGE INTO TABLE STACKOVERFLOW('abc'); -- will not fail
```